# Azure deployment cfn-signal equivalent?

Tags: azure, cloud-init

I am utilizing [cloud-init](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for my deployments both in AWS and Azure.

In AWS I can signal success/failure using cfn-signal to my CloudFormation stack. In Azure I have not found anything similar.

Example cloud-init:

```
#cloud-config
write_files:
  - path: /etc/my_script.sh
    permissions: '0775'
    content: |
      #!/bin/bash
      set -Eeuo pipefail

      trap error_report ERR

      error_report() {
        # Some error reporting stuff, including
        cloud-init collect-logs
        # Send them somewhere
        # cfn-signal -e 1 # Present in AWS-version only
      }

      echo 'This is a successful command'
      # some other commands that might fail
      cfn-signal -e 0     # Present in AWS-version only
runcmd:
  - [ bash, /etc/my_script.sh ]
```

I've read that failing `runcmd` does not fail the whole `cloud-init` configuration. I am missing the piece where I can somehow signal the deployment either a success or failure. Failure would be enough, really.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.